# How to switch BottomNavigationItems in Jetpack Compose without overlapping views?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have somewhat the same setup as the tutorial here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation (see below for the code). There is a difference, I got 2 tabs: a chat tab and a settings tab.

For some reason, I want the chat tab to navigate to the settings tab with a `Button`. But how to do this? If the `onClick` in the `Button` simply navigates to the route of the settings tab, it will just create a new `Settings` view **on top of the chat view**, rather than going to the settings tab.

This is a problem: when the user tabs the chat tab, then the button to go to the settings tab, and re-clicks the chat tab, nothing happens. The settings view is still shown.

How can I navigate from tab A to tab B on a button press without overlapping views?

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
Scaffold(
  bottomBar = {
    BottomNavigation {
      val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
      val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
      items.forEach { screen ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
          icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
          label = { Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId)) },
          selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
          onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.route) {
              // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
              // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
              // on the back stack as users select items
              popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                saveState = true
              }
              // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
              // reselecting the same item
              launchSingleTop = true
              // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
              restoreState = true
            }
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
) { innerPadding ->
  NavHost(navController, startDestination = Screen.Profile.route, Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
    composable(Screen.Profile.route) { Profile(navController) }
    composable(Screen.FriendsList.route) { FriendsList(navController) }
  }
}
```